# _stricmp is not comparing as expected

Tags: c, string, fgets

I wrote this simple script and it just got me crazy.  I cannot understand why the compare I'm doing is always not the same.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
        char test[]="boy";
        char test2[20];

        fgets(test2, 20, stdin);

        if (_stricmp(test2, test) == 0)
        {
            printf("the same");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not");
        }
    }
```

If I insert the word "boy", I still get it wrong.

What is the problem?

Comment: `fgets` includes the trailing newline, try `char test[]="boy\n";`

Comment: @KeineLust Works like charm thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like we should add a new line and then it works great

`char test[]="boy\n"`;

Comment: You should explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered. But adding my answer to address @Jabberwocky comment.

The problem with that program isn't in `_stricmp`, it's in `fgets`. When you type "boy", the `test2` array will be filled with `{ 'b', 'o', 'y', '\n', '\0' }` which isn't equivalent to `{ 'b', 'o', 'y', '\0' }`.

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when **either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read**, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

You have two options to fix this:

- Add the `\n` to the end of `test`, so it becomes `char test[] = "boy\n";`. This could be annoying if you're using that string to do other things and you don't need to add the `\n` to it. For that reason, I recommend the second option.
- Remove the `\n` after reading the input, then compare. Usually, I write my own `GetString` function that solves this problem, and solves the problem when the user input is larger in length than the buffer.

  ```c
  void GetString(char *buffer, int count)
  {
      fgets(buffer, count, stdin);
      fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // Doesn't affect next fgets if user input was larger than buffer size.
      int length = strlen(buffer);
      if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') buffer[length - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the newline.
  }
  ```

Comment: Totally agree with the approach. Instead of running from error; have correct the approach towards the application.